# JSONRPCError : Java Bugzilla integration for login and file a bug

Tags: java, bugzilla

> I am trying to connect Bugzilla to java using j2bugzilla. But i can't
>   login to Bugzilla via following code. response is
>   **{"version":"1.1","error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","message":"method is nothing.","code":100300}}**.  Can anyone point where the issue ?

```
static void callBugzilla() {

        BugClass bugObj = new BugClass();
        bugObj.setComponent("News Reader");
        bugObj.setProduct("MR7");
        bugObj.setSummary("this is a test summary");
        bugObj.setVersion("1.0");

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        // HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters,
        // SO_TIMEOUT);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(
                "http://bugzilla.mycompanyname.org/bugzilla/jsonrpc.cgi?method=User.get&Bugzilla_login=login&Bugzilla_userName=abcd.kg@companyname.in&Bugzilla_password=123456");
        StringEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(bugObj));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(bugObj));

        entity.setContentType("application/json");

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(entity);

        System.out.println("entity:" + httpPostRequest.getEntity());

        // Pass Profile to Server and collect response

        String uploadResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse resp = httpclient1.execute(httpPostRequest);
            System.out.println("resp:" + resp.getStatusLine());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: I know you are not getting far with this but Bugzilla did not understand the request. Check if your version of j2bugzilla and the bugzilla you are trying to talk to is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to connect to the Bugzilla.

```
 BugzillaConnector conn = new BugzillaConnector();
 conn.connectTo("http://bugzilla.mycompanyname.org/bugzilla/", "userName", "password");
 LogIn logIn = new LogIn("userName", "password");
 conn.executeMethod(logIn);
```

and meven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.j2bugzilla</groupId>
    <artifactId>j2bugzilla</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please, do not add comments to your answer. Extend and reformat it.